# Отправка писем Java

Tags: smtp, java, email

Всем привет

Решил прикрутить на моем приложении отправку сообщений на почту клиенту. Так вот, как это лучше реализовать в условиях java Spring? Какой SMTP сервер взять(поднять свой(какой?), или использовать что то, вроде smtp.gmail.com). И что нужно сделать, что бы письма не приходили в спам.

Ну и общие советы желательно, что бы меньше граблей перебирать)

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Доки Спринга](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html)

[Тутор по которому сделал](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/27/send-email-with-spring-javamailsenderimpl-example/)

темку можно закрыть